# MYSQL SELECT multiple values between "" in Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column which returns

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"Properties";i:1;s:14:"Movable Assets";}
```

I would like to return only:

```
Properties, Movable Assets
```

How can I use a select statement to retrieve the values between the " symbols

Comment: This would be fairly difficult considering the fact that the pattern may not be same in all cases. And in mysql there is no such explode function to do the job. The easiest thing would be to use the application layer to handle this.

Comment: I cant use the application layer, this is using a WordPress plugin which only accepts SQL to output a report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.

`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` takes a string argument followed by a delimiter character and the number of parts to return. After you break up the string using the delimiter, that number of parts is returned as a single string.

```
select concat( 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
                'a:2:{i:0;s:10:"Properties";i:1;s:14:"Movable Assets";}',
                '"',
                4
            ),
            '"',
            2
        ),
        '"',
        -1
    ),
    ",",
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                'a:2:{i:0;s:10:"Properties";i:1;s:14:"Movable Assets";}',
                '"',
                4
            ),
            '"',
            4
        ),
        '"',
        -1
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works just but I still have a problem and sorry I didn't mention it in the original question. There are also entries 'Properties' and separately 'Movable Assets'. When using the above answer, these are returned as 'Properties, Properties' and 'Movable Assets, Movable Assets'. Is there a way around this? I am using a case statement before this but I cant filter it out. I tried adding an AND entry_id = 'Properties' then entry_value else, same for 'Movable Assets', but they keep returning duplicates

Comment: Here is the CASE statement: 
MAX(case when field_id = 79 then
(select concat( 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
                entry_value,
                '"',
                4
            ),
            '"',
            2
        ),
        '"',
        -1
    ),
    ",",
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                entry_value,
                '"',
                4
            ),
            '"',
            4
        ),
        '"',
        -1
    )
))
end) as InterestedIn,

Comment: See new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650251/mysql-selecting-words-in-quotation-marks-within-a-column-of-jumbled-text

Answer (score 2):

these are serialize values, you can use php, to get your desired results.

you can use , [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) which will return an array then you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get the comma separated values.

[example](http://codepad.org/5CxaOuzD)

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTRING()`.

Definitions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Or better -- migrate the data to actually be retrievable.