# MySQL selecting words in quotation marks "" within a column of jumbled text

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, substring

I asked a similar question but it has become a larger problem.

The below question catered for 2 options, but not if a single option was stored in the database. See: Use SUBSTRING_INDEX(). Answer by Joyal George:
[MYSQL SELECT multiple values between "" in Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624828/mysql-select-multiple-values-between-in-column/26626458#26626458)

I have a form in WordPress which captures info on people who want to receive updates in certain areas. They can select 1 or more areas.

I then have a reporting plugin which only accepts SQL to retrieve the data for the report. No application layer, only SQL queries to a MYSQL database

If someone only selects 1 area, I need to extract only that area. If they select more than 1 area I need to extract each area separated by a comma. They can select up to 9 areas.

Data in the column is as follows:

1 area:

```
Western Cape
```

Multiple areas:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:10:"North-West";i:1;s:12:"Western Cape";i:2;s:13:"Northern Cape";}
```

I am using a case statement (previous issue with this database structure)

```
select 
a.entry_id, 
MAX(case when field_id = 74 then entry_value end) as FirstName, 
MAX(case when field_id = 75 then entry_value end) as LastName, 
MAX(case when field_id = 76 then entry_value end) as Email, 
MAX(case when field_id = 78 then entry_value end) as Phone, 
MAX(case when field_id = 79 then
(select concat( 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
                entry_value,
                '"',
                4
            ),
            '"',
            2
        ),
        '"',
        -1
    ),
    ",",
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                entry_value,
                '"',
                4
            ),
            '"',
            4
        ),
        '"',
        -1
    )
))
end) as InterestedIn,
MAX(case when field_id = 81 then entry_value end) as Province from ch_arf_entry_values a GROUP BY a.entry_id
```

I need to adjust the 'as InterestedIn' to cater for only 1 input value.

I need to find a solution for the last case 'as Province'

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find a better way to represent what you want, but I think the following comes close:

```
select concat_wc(',', substring_index(substring_index(entry_value, '"', 2), '"' -1),
                 substring_index(substring_index(entry_value, '"', 4), '"' -1),
                 . . .
                )
```

You might have to put a stop condition based on the number of values in the number of values in the string, resulting in something like:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 case when num_entry_values >= 1 then substring_index(substring_index(entry_value, '"', 2), '"' -1) end,
                 case when num_entry_values >= 2 then substring_index(substring_index(entry_value, '"', 4), '"' -1) end,
              . . .
             )
```

If you don't have this number, you can calculate it by counting the number of double quotes in the string.

EDIT:

To count the number of entries, count the `"`:

```
from (select aev.*,
             (length(entry_value) = length(replace(entry_value, '"', '')) ) / 2 as num_entry_values
      from ch_arf_entry_values aev
     ) aev
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't have the number num_entry_values. How can I count this? I used case when (SELECT    
    ROUND ((LENGTH(entry_value)- LENGTH( REPLACE ( entry_value,'”', '') ) ) / LENGTH('”')        
    ) AS count FROM ch_arf_entry_values) >= 1 then ... but it doesnt work :( Is there a way to SELECT COUNT('"') in the variable entry_value?